# Can you have dynamic array inside linked list and its memory allocation

Tags: c++, system-verilog

In systemverilog, I can define struct, so I can make my own linked list
For example,

```
struct node{
int a;
bit my_assoc_array[string];
node* nextNode;
};
```

If i do this, how is the memory allocated for this struct? If this is 32-bit system, so int a will be allocated 4 bytes. How big of memory is allocated for the dynamic associative array and where it starts? For example, typically a char array[10] will have its initial pointer points at the head location.

```
       __     ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ 
 array| -|-->|...|...|...|...|...|...|...|...|...|...|
       --     --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- 
               0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: this is systemverilog syntax for associative array. The key is string type mapped with value type bit.

Comment: systemverilog is based sort on c++

Comment: I don't really understand what's going on, but it sure doesn't feel like this question should be tagged with `c++` but I'll leave it for now.

Comment: i am not quit comfortable to ask such a question too. But i sort of feel that this can be explained in memory allocation concepts in c and c++, tho with a weird use of associative array here.

Comment: C++ does not define the exact layout this would be in.   It would require complete knowledge of all the data types involved and the compiler (and flags) used to compile the code to answer your question.

Comment: In regard to your last sentence, declaring an array via `char array[10];` does not create a pointer in either `C` or `C++`.

Comment: ok let me clarify; char * p = array. P points to the head. so array in my understanding, points to the head initially.

Comment: so if this would happen on stack, 10 char space is created on stack with a initial pointer to its head element named array is what char array[10] means to me.

Comment: @dgnuff i care about the starting point is because associative array is sparse format. for example, it can save data at array[1] array[4] array[8] discretely without saving anything in between,

Comment: "so array in my understanding, points to the head initially."  No, that's a very bad way to think about it.  An array is a contiguous area to hold multiple copies of whatever object it is, e.g. `char`.  `array[n]` refers directly to the nth element, without any pointers being involved.  The compiler knows, at compile time where the elements of the array are stored, so given any index into the array, it can directly compute the address of the element in question.  It does this without needing a pointer to the head element of the array.

Comment: interesting. the graph here i show appears to be used by many text book and websites.and by what you say char. array[n] refers directly to the nth element. i have to disagree since this is a declaration without refering to any specific element of it.

Comment: A plain array involves no pointers, but the array will decay into a pointer to the first element in many situations. An `std::vector` does use a pointer that points to the internal array on the heap though, and if you dynamically allocate an array, you of course store a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @fei xiang makes more sense. thanks.

Comment: @dgnuff by the way, im asking how the memory are allocated pgysically. not how compiler compile. when you declare a fixed array, what happens in memory allocation?

Comment: If you say `char array[12];` within a function, all that happens in terms of allocation , using MSVC on x86, is that the function prolog code subtracts 12 from `esp` to create a space of 12 bytes on the stack.  End of story.  It's a damn sight more complex for a file scope variable, since it involves making sure space is allocated (usually in `.bss`), and setting up a label properly, because the linker will get involved in sorting out where accesses go.   ...

Comment: ok. but it also needs to know where the space for this array starts. so this starting point gets saved. In any way of speaking, I want to clarify how the memory saves this damn thing. And I logically assume it has to save something to tell, ok, this is my starting point, and this is my size, and even for later garbage collection.

Comment: ... Likewise, if a `class` / `struct` contains an array, space is allocated in the `class` / `struct` to hold the array, but all that happens is that the compiler *internally* notes the offset of the array within the struct.  In the case of a class, under MSVC x86, this is typically in `ECX`, so all references to your array in that case will be automatically computed as offsets from `ECX`.  Let me repeat this.  The compiler does not ever directly create a pointer to the array, in all cases it can determine where it is without needing a pointer.

Comment: "ok. but it also needs to know where the space for this array starts. so this starting point gets saved. "   NO NO NO.  The compiler knows that accesses to the array are done via offsets from `ESP`.  The "starting point" is typically a private number, known only to the compiler that is an offset from `ESP` to the base of the array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176984/discussion-between-dgnuff-and-user3431800).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SystemVerilog does not let you see the internal representation of a struct, or any other datatype for that matter. The closest it comes is providing handles to class objects. But it does provide a number of built-in data types that reduces the need for such knowledge. For example, it has a queue which gives you the functionality of a linked list.

Comment: thank you dave. Do you know how memory is allocated for dynamic array like associative array in systemverilog internally? how much memory it will get when it is declared and nothing in it at compile time? if there is memory allocated, will it also points to the starting address of this memory chunk?

Comment: Memory allocation is much more complicated in SystemVerilog than in most other programming languages due to events created by changing values. You should not be concerned with such topics unless you are trying to build a simulator yourself.